# Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating $2y^2$ about line $y=2$.

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem: find the volume generated by rotating $x=2y^2$, with $y\ge 0$, up to $x=2$, about the line line $y=2$

Here is my attempt:

$$V=2\pi\int_0^2(y-2)(2-2y^2)dy=2\pi\left[\frac{2y^2}2-\frac{2y^4}4-4y+\frac{4y^3}3\right]_0^2$$

The correct answer is $13\pi/3$.
What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use MathJax to format your equations. See for example here [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Then draw a picture. It should be immediately that the upper limit is wrong. When $x=2$ you get $2=2y^2$ so $y=1$. If you have any $y>1$ then the corresponding $x$ is greater than $2$. Then the volume is $$V=2\pi\int_0^1(2-y)(2-2y^2)dy=2\pi\int_0^1(4-2y-4y^2+2y^3)dy=\frac{13}3\pi$$

Comment: Thank you for telling me about MathJax, it will make it easier for me in the future if I ask questions. I see my mistake now. I was thinking about this before I seen this answer and this reaffirms that I was correct in my thinking. Im going to try it for myself on paper now, thank you !!!!

Comment: I've edited your question, so you have an example as well. Good luck.